# Entropy-based histograms for database selectivity

Tags: python, database, relational-database, histogram, entropy

I'm trying to implement an Entropy based histogram based on this [paper](http://infolab.usc.edu/DocsDemos/to-CIKM13.pdf) (PDF Warning!) but the maximum entropy algorithm pseudo-code is not clear at all.

They are calculating the "area" of a bucket doing ai = fi*si  (Section 4.2) where fi is the frequency of i value, and si is the "spread". The first issue is that I'm not sure what spread is, but based on reference [16] it should be (v_(i+1) - v_i) which means "distance with the next item".

However, on the algorithm, they use Ab as an area list on line7 (for example), and as frequency on line 14 (for example). So It's not clear if ab is a list of areas, frequencies, or if they are just interchanging them randomly...

Can you help me clearing out the pseudo-code? I have done an implementation in python but it's not working, I get negative values for `localMinH`:

```
def build_struct(self):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    self.calculateFrequency()
    self.calculateArea()
    self.splits = []
    self.entropies = {}
    minHeap = [(self.H(self.frequency.keys()), 0, len(self.frequency), 0)]
    while len(self.splits) < self.parameter:
        previous = minHeap
        minHeap = []
        for bucket in previous:
            a = bucket[1]
            b = bucket[2]
            wb = sum(self.areas[a:b])
            if wb > 1:
                tr = sum(self.frequency.keys()[a:b])
                locCutPos = tl = hl = 0
                localMinH = -1
                hr = ho = self.H(self.frequency.keys()[a:b])
                for j in xrange(len(self.areas[a:b]) - 1):
                    x = self.frequency[self.frequency.keys()[j+a]]
                    tl += x
                    tr -= x
                    hl = self.H2(x/(x+tl), tl/(x+tl)) + (tl/(tl+x))*hl
                    #print a,b,x,tr
                    hr = (hr - self.H2(x/tr, (tr-x)/tr))* (tr/(tr-x))
                    hmenos = ho - (hl + hr)
                    if (localMinH == -1) or (hmenos < localMinH):
                        locCutPos = j
                        localMinH = hmenos
                print wb, localMinH
                heapq.heappush(minHeap, (wb*localMinH, a, a+locCutPos, locCutPos))
                heapq.heappush(minHeap, (wb*localMinH, a+locCutPos, b, locCutPos))
        bucket = minHeap[0]
        self.splits.append(bucket[1] + bucket[3])
        self.entropies[bucket[1] + bucket[3]] = bucket[0]
```

`self.frequency` is is a dict with the values as keys and frequency as value. and self.areas is just a list of the areas.